# iPhone Pull Down Refresh like Tweetie

Tags: iphone, uitableview, pull-to-refresh

I am trying to find an example of placing an element above the Table View outside the normal scrollable region. How would I do this? An example would be what the Tweetie 2 app for the iPhone does to refresh tweets.

Sample code would be extremely helpful.

Comment: If you do use this, be mindful that there is a patent pending for the concept: http://appft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-adv.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&d=PG01&p=1&S1=20100199180.PGNR.&OS=dn/20100199180&RS=DN/20100199180

Comment: Interesting, I know Tweetie did it best, not sure it did this first. Also to note that this question was asked well before the patent was even filed.

Comment: I believe that when the patent is filed is irrelevant. The criteria is "when did Tweetie 2 release this functionality," and "did anyone else release a product that did the same thing before them?"

Comment: Hate to say this, but it should be criminal to patent a paradigm that users expect to work, especially one like this one.

Comment: Software related patents are irrelevant outside USA

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I did find the answer to my own question, for anyone who is interested.

[EGOTableViewPullRefresh](http://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh)

I tried this solution and it works great! It is almost identical to the Tweetie Pull Down refresh.

Comment: I spent a little bit of time on EGOTableViewPullRefresh today and moved the main code into a UITableViewController subclass, it might be easier for some people to implement. 

http://github.com/jessedc/EGOTableViewPullRefresh

Comment: I think the EGOTableViewPullRefrehsh isn't a very easy solution. But if you can use it: It's the best way ;-)

Comment: I can't find a license on the github site.

Comment: @titaniumdecoy It's in the source: https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh/blob/master/EGOTableViewPullRefresh/Classes/View/EGORefreshTableHeaderView.m

Comment: I think `EGOTableViewPullRefresh` doesn't supported by author. 2 years no commits. Is `enormego` alive?

Answer (score 20):

Here's an alternative to EGOTableViewPullRefresh:

http://blog.leahculver.com/2010/12/iphone-pull-to-refresh.html

Source available on github here:

https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh

It's slightly easier to use from the developers point of view, though I did go with EGOTableViewPullRefresh in the end as I preferred how it looked.

Comment: It has a bug when you use it with plain table that has sections. When you scroll up while refreshing, table cells will appear above section header.

Answer (score 4):

Start with iOS 6.0, there is a standard control called UIRefreshControl within sdk.  [apple doc here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRefreshControl_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 3):

Here what you can do with iOS 6 and later:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 
    // other initialization
    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self
                            action:@selector(myRefresh)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}
```

Your refresh method:

```
- (void)myRefresh {  
    // get refreshed data for table view
}
```

You end refreshing in reloadData:

```
- (void)reloadData {  
    [self.tableView reloadData];  

    // End the refreshing   
    if (self.refreshControl) {  
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];  
    }  
}
```

Then you are all set!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for UIRefreshControl which is available for every UITableViewController - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRefreshControl_class/Reference/Reference.html