# UITableView "Scroll down to update"

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4

What is the easiest way to implement "Scroll down to update" functionality like in facebook "News feed" when you scroll down the news from top you see an update indicator and it update the news accordingly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone Pull Down Refresh like Tweetie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634739/iphone-pull-down-refresh-like-tweetie)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at the following projects on github:

http://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh

http://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh

Answer (score 4):

This feature became popular in Tweetie application, that has since been bought and re-branded as the official Twitter iPhone application.

I think you will find what you are looking for here...

[stackoverflow - iPhone Pull Down Refresh like Tweetie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634739/iphone-pull-down-refresh-like-tweetie)

[github -  enormego / EGOTableViewPullRefresh](http://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh)

[github - UITableViewController subclass](http://github.com/jessedc/EGOTableViewPullRefresh)

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting to iOS 6 devices, you can use [UIRefreshControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIRefreshControl_class/Reference/Reference.html). [Here's an example of how to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607015/uirefreshcontrol-ios-6-xcode)