# iOS app submission: The App is using a private API: _tableView

Tags: ios, ios6

We have submitted an app to the app store and Apple send us a review note that

> The App is using a private API: _tableView

I have tested in my code. I am not sure what exactly Apple is asking us to change.

I just used https://github.com/shiki/STableViewController for pull to refresh. Help me please as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The process of determining [whether your app uses Private APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2842873/119114) is probably not as simple as you might expect.

It is possible for Apple to [falsely identify your app as containing Private API usage, even when it doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3546046/119114).

This can happen if you write code that has naming conflicts with code in the Apple frameworks.  I'm wondering if the Apple process isn't getting stuck on this in `STableViewController.h`:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *tableView;
```

That's probably not the best name (even though it makes sense that a *table view controller* would have a `tableView` property), because [UITableViewController has a property with the same name](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewController/tableView).

You might try simply editing the `STableViewController` source code yourself, and renaming that property (*e.g.* to `sTableView`, or something more unique):

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *sTableView;
```

*(and, of course, refactoring the code to change all **usage** of that property, too)*

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where STableViewController is using _tableView. But why are you using it? What's wrong with UIRefreshControl?

[UIRefreshControl iOS 6 xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607015/uirefreshcontrol-ios-6-xcode)

Comment: Maybe Deniel needs to support iOS 5.

Comment: I would use UIRefreshControl on iOS 6 and put a "refresh" button in the navigation bar or something on iOS 5. Not pretty, but it works and you don't have to rely on third party code that may be buggy or cause you to violate the developer terms/conditions without realising it.

Comment: That does not really solve the problem, does it @AbhiBeckert? Maybe you want to try a better maintained project like: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/isrefreshcontrol instead of one that has not been updated for 2 years.

Comment: Our requirement is Pull up for more items so that's why we used this code.

Comment: Personally I would never ship any iOS app where I "require" any third party library, unless the library is bundled with iOS. I would treat STableViewController and ISRefreshControl as sample code only, and implement it myself - or else don't have pull to refresh in the app. That way you will avoid situations like this one, where you have an unexpected problem that cannot be solved easily. Almost every third party library I have ever used in my entire career has eventually ended up being a mistake.