# RSS feed core data save in uitableview

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, rss

I created an RSS Reader from a blog. I am retrieving the articles of the blog and i am filling an uitableview with them in a navigation controller. Which is the best way refresh my tableview when i want and also to save RSS feed in my app in order to use it offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) For the refreshing part you can use a refresh `UIBarButtonItem` on the `NavigationBar` or the `pull-to-refresh` (Find good answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607015/uirefreshcontrol-ios-6-xcode)). In my opinion I think using the `UIBarButtonItem` is a bit old fashioned.

2) You can store the contents you get from your RSS feed in the app using CoreData. CoreData is a framework provided by Apple. Look up the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdBasics.html).