# How to reproduce Three20 Slide Up To Refresh feature?

Tags: iphone, three20

I would like to add this to a projet, but I don't want to add the full Three20 framework for a simple feature. How the framework does to always hide the first row, and to detect when it's sliding up ? After that, I suppose a callback url can just be called to refresh the table view.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of the standalone implementations, like [EGOTableViewPullRefresh](http://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh).

Credit noted in this StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634739/iphone-pull-down-refresh-like-tweetie) also; which is where I first learned of it.

Comment: No problem. If it's solved your problem, it'd be nice if you vote the answer up too. Cheers