# Facebook iPhone app and HTML

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook, ios4

If you have a look at Facebook news feed on the native
 iPhone/iPod mobile app

You will notice that it loads an HTML page? Is this true? Not using a grid table list view? How does it do this? And how does it do the pull down relOad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native app does not load an HTML page. It's written in Objective-C and centered around a library called [Three 20](http://three20.info/).

Check out this thread on pull to refresh functionality: [iPhone Pull Down Refresh like Tweetie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634739/iphone-pull-down-refresh-like-tweetie)

Comment: actually it does load an html page.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: I've had it many times on bad connections where everything will load except the main HTML comment in the middle. Or you will notice new functionality without an app update. The biggest evidence is occasionally the CSS file won't load and its real clear it's HTML.

Comment: It would appear from the three20 site that elements of the Facebook app are written in Obj-C. That said, it almost certainly loads HTML for actual content.

Comment: The Facebook app is written in objective-c however the content is in fact HTML. It doesn't call a web screen get the response of the web service then use it in objective-c code, the entire content screen is html! (OffBySome is right, I have also experienced the same thing).