# How to rebuild the email-app (specificly the mail-overview)?

Tags: iphone, ios, email, ios4

I want to reabuild the email-app one to one for a private-message system.

I am working at the moment on the email-overview-screen.

[image]

Now I have a ViewController for this with a UITableView and a UINavigationBar on it.

2 simple questions:

1. How do I get more then one line in the cell, specificly 2-4
   different font-types (bold / not bold / blue) exactly rebuilded as
   seen in the link above?
2. How do I can add a PullDown-Refresh functionality? (You know, this
   pull down, oh refrash, thing, emails have)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a custom cell, you can put in whatever information and links and styles as you want. You can even use UIWebViews as the cells, which could make styling and links easier.
2. Many examples of this have a look at the answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1634739/41116).

Comment: Apple does not recommend `UIWebViews` in `UITableViewCell`s, because of too much overhead. Better to go with styled `UILabel`s.