# iOS 7 Styled Pull-To-Refresh

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, pull-to-refresh

Do anyone know an open source for Pull-To-Refresh control like the mail app in iOS 7? Lots of apps use it, so I think there should be one. It would be perfect, because I would save quite a time.

Comment: Do you mean the UIRefreshControl?That's part of iOS, you don't need any open source code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Pull Down Refresh like Tweetie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634739/iphone-pull-down-refresh-like-tweetie)

Comment: try [SurfingRefreshControl](https://github.com/peiweichen/SurfingRefreshControl)

Answer (score 4):

Pull to refresh is actually available in iOS 6.

[Here is a tutorial for you.](http://www.lextech.com/2012/10/ios-6-pull-to-refresh-tutorial/)

[Pre iOS 6](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for UIRefreshControl which is available for every UITableViewController - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRefreshControl_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

TRY SVPullToRefresh or ZBARSDK